# What is the best way to deploy changes in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

We already have a Laravel web app hosted in the cloud (AWS EC2 instance). Let's say that changes will be required to be made, such as revising the (blade view) layout or adding new reports.

After I make the changes to the local controller, view and route files, do I simply copy them to the cloud host? Laravel keeps a cache of the blade view files. Will they be updated when the blade view files are updated? What other items do I need to do?

Comment: dont you familiar with version controlling ? like git?

Answer (score 2):

The views caches will be automatically regenerated, but you can force delete the cache if you want. `php artisan cache:clear`.

For routes, it's parsed from the file, so no worry there.

If you change config at some point, make sure to run `php artisan config:clear`.

If you touch the services and something is still not working, try `php artisan clear-compiled`. it will force the regen of the bootstrap.

Comment: I'll try it out. Thank you :-)

Answer (score 1):

For deploying PHP applications in any framework, you can use various tools. The most simple is [PHP Deployer](https://deployer.org/), and i recommend you to use it if you're not familiar with automatic deployment. You can set a sequence of commands which will be launched during deployment e.g.

1. git pull origin master
2. php artisan cache:clear
3. php artisan migrate

Comment: I'll check it out. Thanks for the info :-)

Answer (score 1):

The best way would be to use a source version control software like git and implement a pipeline on a service like GitLab.

I recently implemented one with [this](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/examples/laravel_with_gitlab_and_envoy/) tutorial.

It exploits GitLab pipelines and Larvel's Envoy to automatically run tests and deploy your code that passed each stage you defined. It also allows you to rollback to previous versions at any given time.